# Empty Diagnostic/Performance tools in VS 2022

Tags: c#, debugging, visual-studio-2022, diagnostic-tools

I am attempting to debug my code through Visual Studio 2022 (Version 17.2.6) and cannot for the life of me seem to figure out why my diagnostic tools are not populating with performance metrics. The Events are able to appear through the 'Events' tab but that's just about it.

Mainly want to record CPU metrics to see some bottlenecks within the code and am not sure how else to perform this is the panel is just empty. There does not seem to be a whole lot of other examples out there. Has anyone come across this situation?

[image: example]

Comment: Your diagnostic tools window looks different than mine https://i.stack.imgur.com/wcCoV.png - you seem to be missing the whole top toolbar portion.

Comment: Yes very strange, there's no option either to select the toolbar either, from previous instances I worked with VS its always displayed it

Comment: I tried a few things but couldn't reproduce the problem. Can you tell me what you did to cause this problem so that I can reproduce the problem and find a solution. I can only give you a few suggestions right now:
1. Reset all settings under Tools>Import And Export Settings.
2. Repair VS.
3. Delete and reinstall VS.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.

Reinstalling WebView2 in apps & features resolved the issue for me.

Steps copy/pasted from the Q/A forums:

1. Open Settings(Windows) > App > App & features > search for webview2 > find Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime > click Modify > click Repair. If Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime wasn’t installed, please go to https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=2124703, download and run the installer.
2. Run VS as administrator.
3. Try to update Windows OS.
   Run CMD as administrator and run DISM.exe /Online /Cleanup-image /Restorehealth command, after it finishes, run sfc /scannow command.

Try that out and see if that fixes your issue.