# Empty Diagnostic Tools Window

Tags: visual-studio, maui

I am working on a .NET MAUI App with VS 17.9.0 Preview 2 and wanted to run the Debug and Diagnostic Tools.

First of all, I thought this Window was empty because it maybe does not support .NET 7
But now, I switched to .NET 8 and it

[image]

I found the link to [Empty Diagnostic/Performance tools in VS 2022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73141662/empty-diagnostic-performance-tools-in-vs-2022) and it recommended to repair and re-install "Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime", but this also did not help.

What is the reason for that and is there a way to repair it and display it?

Comment: Diagnostic Tools starts automatically when running .NET8 MAUI project on Windows platform, is your problem that Diagnostic Tools displays the interface in the screenshot when the project is running?

Comment: Yes, when I launch my App the via Visual Studio in Debug-Mode it just shows up like this. I am working under Windows (not Mac) on a .NET MAUI App (.net 7 or .net 8) and am running the App on Android/iOS Simulator. Currently, I have no Windows Target in the App configuration. Need to analyze Memory consumption and object creation regarding Memory Leaks and if it is .NET MAUI related or even within my Code. Memory consumption is increasing when I open and close my BottomSheet Control and activated some Toggle Buttons. Is the Diagnostic Tools Window only available on .NET MAUI Windows Targets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Which tools are supported for my project?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/profiling/choose-performance-tool?view=vs-2022#which-tools-are-supported-for-my-project) document, Diagnostic Tools currently only supports performance testing when running the project on the Windows platform.

If you wish to test the performance of the project on the iOS/Android platform, you can deploy the project to physical device for testing. For specific operation steps, please refer to [Device provisioning for iOS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/ios/device-provisioning/?view=net-maui-8.0) and [Set up Android device for debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/android/device/setup?view=net-maui-8.0).

Additionally, you mentioned the absence of a Windows Target in the App configuration.
For this situation, you should to make sure that the `<TargvetFrameworks>` tag in the project's `.csproj` file contains the following code:

```
<TargetFrameworks Condition="$([MSBuild]::IsOSPlatform('windows'))">$(TargetFrameworks);net8.0-windows10.0.19041.0</TargetFrameworks>
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. I also tested with a Windows Target, but unfortunately the UI seems to be not supported. Lot‘s of elements missing. I need to make a separate button then to show the BottomSheet. Once done, I could let you know. But, as you mentioned, Diagnostic Tools Window now shows its output. Thanks for your help!

Comment: On physical device I did not have success as I described here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77702152/net-maui-app-crashes-when-working-on-observablerangcollection-watchdog-termina